# Saving all FB chats using Selenium Python

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, web-scraping, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to save all the chats from FaceBook to local machine.
I'm using selenium webdriver via python for the same but issue is I'm unable to open every chat and copy content.
Although I can save chat section that indicates I've had chat with users using this code:

```
chatnames = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_st"]/div[1]/ul/li[1]')
chatname = [x.text for x in chatnames]
print(chatname)
```

And output is:

> Conversation List\nUser1\n12:39pm\nYou: yes say\nUser2\n7/23/17\nYou
>   are now connected on Messenger.\nUser3\n7/17/17\nYou are now connected
>   on Messenger.\nUser4\n7/4/17\nYou are now connected on Messenger...

Could you please help me opening each chat and extracting chat.

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use _Facebook API_ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
chatname=str(chatname)
print(chatname)
```

Maybe it will help...

Comment: Thanks for your input but I was looking for code that iterates through all chats but this code will only copy data of chat that is already open.

Comment: I do not have facebook, so I can't help you anymore. Sorry.